# How to further my playing of Jungle Lee Sin?

Tags: league-of-legends

My main and favorite role in League of Legends is Jungle Lee Sin. Lee Sin is an amazing champion with amazing mobility, great ganks, and amazing jungle clear.

I usually start red and then gank top immediately. I build assassin Lee Sin and build full AD, with the occasional tanky item. After Hunter's Machete and 5 pots, I occasionally build to Madreds Razors.  Afterwards I build towards Sightstone, Bloodthirsters, upgrade to Maw, get Ravenous Hydra.
My masteries are 21/9/0 with points in AD and Armor Penetration and in reduced creep damage. My runes are Flat AD Quints, Flat AD Reds, Flat Armor Yellows, and Scaling Magic Resist Blues.  I smartcast all abilities except my ult. I don't smartcast any items but slot 3 which is for the sightstone.

To get to the point, I play very well in a normal game and usually have a positive k/d ratio. I play strong and am able to ward jump proficiently to make a clean escape or occasionally chase, I make my skillshots 9/10 times, so I don't know what the problem is when I play ranked. I usually do okay but sometimes my team just can't play (sadly I am stuck in Bronze 5) or when I play against the enemy team, they play super passively and because of that, I can't gank them because they can get under their turret very quickly. I feel I can't do anything late game in team fights either. At a point I just backdoor, but the opposing team usually sees me and ganks me, leaving me dead to watch my team lose. I can never get my items unless I take all of my teams laning kills. I can't farm because the laners get upset if I take their CS. I can't manage well in time when ganking and jungling. I do not think I am a bad player, despite bronze 5, honestly play with me and you'll see. But I know I rely too much on enemy play style, and I want to know how to better play Lee Sin so I can be a good ranked player.

**How can I become a better Lee Sin Jungler?**

Being a better player means I need to know:
- How do I get proper gold?
- How do I play against passive players?
- How do I improve my late game?

Comment: Can you please edit your question into a _much_ more concise form? It's to detect a _question_ in this wall of text...

Comment: He's asking how to be a better jungler in ranked play, I shortened it a bit and made the question more clear if my edit gets accepted

Comment: @hammythepig you did make the question more precise but you cut off some parts of it by focusing too much on Lee Sin. I think his frustration was mainly on him being stuck on Bronze 5 - which he did by playing Lee Sin. My answer for example focuses more on how to get UNstuck from Bronze rather than how to play Lee Sin better (which he already does according to his question). My answer might be a bit off topic after your edit but I'm not changing it since it refers to his original question. I'm just saying this here so I can justify why I went that way.

Comment: @PanagiotisPalladinos yes, I did assume he wants to continue playing as Lee Sin, as his first sentence said it was his main and he talked of no other champs.  I guess we'll just have to wait and see if he wants to focus on Lee or just getting out of Bronze 5, but yup you're fully justified :)

Comment: Watch insekt play, take notes, do those things :)

Comment: Believe me I have. I have read a numerous amount of guides. I have watched many gameplays especially from Insec and StVicious. Using the wardjump kick to team by insec, I have gotten a lot better. Even though it sounds stupid, I haven't learned that much more. It seems like they can always do well no matter the situation. I watched what they do, but it doesn't always work for me. Like how they balance jungling and ganks.

Comment: your problem i think, is that you seem proficient in only one role and one champion. I can effectively play all roles as well as dominate mid lane or jungle with 3-4 different champions. Not saying i don't have my bad games occasionally but i do good. In reality no guide will ever help you, playing duo with someone willing to help you get better, will

Answer (score 5):

As a jungle I can see some mistake in your speech ... and Iwill point it out so you can see where you can improve in my opinion :

> I usually start red and then gank top immediately

you can't just do that all the time you have to adapt your route to your team, the other team and the other jungler

Solutions :

- Identify the lane that you think /will be pushed fast/is strong early/could snowball/ and try to finish your route near this lane (lvl 3) and gank this lane.
- Think of what route the opposite jungler will take and /couter jungle/Counter gank/ him (Lee sin is very effective for that)
- ...

> I build assassin Lee Sin and build full AD, with the occasional tanky item.

- Adapt your build to the enemy team and the needs of your team

even if you prefer building AD you can just no brain build.

> usually have a positive k/d ratio

It doesn't matter not your job ;-)

> I can't gank them because they can get under their turret very quickly.

If they are under their tower they should be dominated

You could try going in their back ward jump Q > R > Q 
so you get them out of their tower and you follow them out of turret range with the resonating strike (just an idea)

If you can get them out of their tower tank 3 tower shot and leave your laner take the kill it would be a very good play

> I feel I can't do anything late game in team fights either

Your role as a Lee Sin in team fight could be :

- Engage and kick 1 carry out of their team and then instant kill him
- Kick someone anoying away from your carries (the most important)
- Slow the peoples that chase your carries
- Shield your carries
- CC the other carries to help yours kill them

> At a point I just backdoor, but the opposing team usually sees me and ganks me, leaving me dead to watch my team lose.

Stop dooing that... stay with your team.

> I can never get my items unless I take all of my teams laning kills.

Stop thinking like that and imagine what your carries could do with this gold if you had give them the kill(s)

To conclude, as a jungle your role is not to carry your team ... It's to carry your carries so they can carry the team ;-)
Most of the champion are a lot more gold efficient than lee sin... So I think you should try to play FOR your team or change your position to Lee Sin Mid.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It laid out everything pretty simply.

Comment: great answer, couldn't agree more. Love the carry your carries so they can carry. Unless your heca -_-

Answer (score 2):

So your question is basically how to be effective with Lee Sin in Bronze Division.

I would have to say that many people who are stuck in Bronze are sometimes not worth being bronze in terms of playstyle. But for various reasons you just can't get out of it. I've never experienced it since my ranking matches got me to Silver immediately and I kept going up from there.

BUT I can make some speculations and give some general advice.

1. For me the jungler is a very special role. He can be a key role to winning the game BUT he can rely a lot on teammates. If you do well as a jungler but your team is a mess in lanes then you can't do much to help. And like you said as Lee Sin you will fall off late game which means that your fate is pretty much sealed.
   So first advice is the most radical one. If you are solo queue and stuck in bronze try another role (not jungler). If you think you are better than the rest of your teammates most of the times, try a more late game role like ADC or AP caster.
2. Never let your teammates know that you are better than them. The fact that you are bronze 5 and that you think it's entirely not your fault can be frustrating sometimes and you might find yourself giving up early in the game or not trying as much or blaming teammates a lot. Don't do that. Especially to low elo players, because all you will achieve is them complaining and not focusing, at best.
3. Snowballing is much more efficient in low elo games. So champions who are dominant early can give a huge boost to the team. Lee Sin "can be" one of those champions. If you get early game kills try to push your advantage as much as possible don't just lay back and farm. Winning games in 20 minutes should be your goal. I've noticed this by playing in the european server with a new account and with friends that are in Bronze. It would be nice for example if you could pick last or trade with the last pick of your team so you can get the best pubstopming champion you can get without the other team countering you.

I'll only give you those 2 advice since I wanna focus on them. The second one is really underrated so try and make your teammates feel better and trust me you will see a LOT of improvement.

Comment: what is your IGN want to play a normal game?

Comment: @Kubtops What server are you on?

Comment: NA my ign is kubtops.

Comment: Whats yours? @ Panagiotis Palladinos

Comment: @Kubtops I added you in game ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I main Lee Sin Jungle and so far this season I have a consistant 24/7 W:L in Diamond 5.Now i am not writing a book on the how to pro lee sin, because although I consider myself a good lee sin player, there are many better players out there than me but I will give 1 or 2 tips just for you stuck lower in elo.

Don't go glass cannon, you can be 100/0 but as just AD and some defence, a small amount of cc and you are dead. For me there are 2 ways you can play lee sin, Tank and Hybrid, Tank is mainly so you can peel and soak damgae for your team at a genrally lower cost thatn if you were to buy full AD, hybrid is for fairly confident Lee Sin players that know how to take use of an advantage.

Secondly, Share your kills, honestly I don't care about K/D at all, 0/3/9 Is much better than if you were 3/0/2, If you give the laners more kills, they will snowball better into mid/late game, and trust me, It also makes them feel better about themselves, which means they have a higher morale, and momentum. Which Ultimately means you will win more games, Good luck :)

P-S I will answer any questions you ask since, I have plenty of time on my hands :)

Answer (score -1):

Lee Sin is considered as must-know-how-to-play by [best junglers in the world](http://leaguepedia.com/wiki/Diamondprox#LCS_All_Stars). Yes he is strong early but falls late.

You don't have proper direct question so I will give you some resources that will help you with your jungle LoL carrier ;)

- [Lolking Lee Sin Builds with tips and maps how to jungle](http://www.lolking.net/guides/list.php?champion=leesin)
- [LoL Pro Lee Sin 7 page guide](http://www.lolpro.com/guides/lee-sin/286-lee-sin-build-guide-jungle-by-al-cwcwcw)
- [General LoL Pro how to jungle](http://www.lolpro.com/guides/game-play/199-how-to-jungle)
- For example [YouTube video with gameplay of 2500 elo/Diamond I Lee Sin jungle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6QYWMDQk-w)

Ah! And most important thing - **play him as often as possible!**

Good luck.

Comment: I agree with you in principle BUT Bronze 5 is another world.
I wouldn't say that being a better Lee Sin (which he already states to be) would help him that much. I don't really understand the downvote that much though... It's not an offtopic answer or anything.

Comment: Not the down voter, but this answer was probably down voted because it is a mostly a link only answer.

Comment: @ColinD the question is so open that I don't see how to direct answer. I think that at least one of this resources will help OP.

Comment: @ColinD question is so general that every of this issues can be discussed for hours :) I don't see how to answer other than give a sources of LoL Lee Sin knowledge.

Comment: @iber, if you can't provide a clear answer, you can always wait for the question to be edited/closed or post your general info as a comment. Answering bad questions is an invitation for more bad questions.

Comment: @ColinD I don't agree with this statement. Often answering show OP how question should be improved. Ignoring so called "bad" questions isn't sollution. I would love to improve my answer but OP aren't in this disscusion and we can only guess what he/she has in his/her mind.

Comment: i dont agree with your second sentence, 'Yes he is strong early but falls late'. IMHO Lee Sin is a very strong (if not one of the strongest) late game junglers but he has a very high learning curve. Lee is a very clasic case of easy to learn, hard to master. His pressence in teamfights is amazing since he can completely nullify one of the enemy team. (be i to throw the tank away from the front lanes or to kick the adc/apc away so they cant hit your squishies.